# Can a function parameter hide another functions identifier?

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, misra

Static code analysis identifies the constructor parameters `begin` and `end` as names that hide the corresponding member functions (read functions) according to Misra Rule 2-10-2 (Identifiers declared in an inner scope shall not hide an identifier declared in an outer scope).
Is this correct?

```
template <typename T>
class TLineSegment
{
public:
   TLineSegment(const point_type& begin, const point_type& end)
      : m_begin(begin)
      , m_end(end)
   {
   }

   const point_type& begin() const
   {
      return m_begin;
   }

   const point_type& end() const
   {
      return m_end;
   }

private:
   point_type m_begin;
   point_type m_end;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Inside the constructor, writing `begin` always refers to the parameter (unless you explicitly prefix it with `this->`)

Comment: But wouldn't I - the same way I would always refer to the parameter with ```begin``` -  always refer to the member function when writing ```begin()```?

Comment: @Max No, `begin()` would try to invoke `operator()` on the parameter (which probably does not exist). The parentheses are not part of the name.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why the rule exists. You have a parameter `const point_type& begin` and a member function `const point_type& begin()`... quite confusing. The de facto standard way to name the member functions would be `get_begin()` etc. _Unless_ you are coding an `iterator`-like interface, then the member names _should_ be begin and end, and you'd have to rename the parameters instead.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, this MISRA rule is about code readability and avoiding confusion rather then having code broken.

So from syntactical point of view, your program is correct, but from the MISRA point of view, it violates this rule, because it overwrites already existing identifier.

If put to extreme, some programmer not paying much attention might be confused by using the same names.

But from practical view, this is really a detail and in my opinion may be left as you have it. But if your company forces MISRA rules, you should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler looks first at **names**, and **then** figures out what to do with them. So `begin` is the name of the function argument. The compiler won’t look past that to see if there’s some other definition that can be used in the function call.